# Can I use foreign health insurance for US taxes?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, working-abroad, israel

I am a US citizen living abroad, and I have government-provided health insurance (that is, provided by the government of the country I live in).  Does this qualify as health insurance for the purposes of ACA and the tax requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [fulfill](http://www.usexpattaxhelp.com/obamacare-taxes-us-expats-americans-living-abroad.php)

> the bona fide resident test or the physical presence test, you are
>   considered to have essential minimum coverage under the Act and will
>   not be required get affordable health care insurance or pay the
>   penalty under the PPACA for the month or months that you qualify for
>   either of these tests.

The [bona fide resident test](http://www.usexpattaxhelp.com/us-expat-what-is-bona-fide-resident-test.php) requires that:

> You must be bona fide resident of a foreign country or countries for
>   an uninterrupted period that includes an entire tax year. This means
>   for most taxpayers January 1 – December 31 and
>
> You must be either:
>
> - A U.S. citizen, or
> - A U.S. resident alien who is a citizen or national of a country with    which the United States has an income tax treaty in effect.

The [physical presence test](http://www.usexpattaxhelp.com/us-citizens-what-is-physical-presence-test.php) requires that:

> - You must be physically present in a foreign country or countries for at least 330 full calendar days during a period of 12 consecutive
>     months
> - Be a US citizen and resident alien